# Udev rule not working on Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, usb, virtual-machine, udev

I can detect and mount my USB drive on my Debian VM machine. And the first post [here](http://www.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1290438) - explained below - works on my Ubuntu machine. Should not it work on Debian too? It doesn't of course. Why is that?

Concretely, create a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d`:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="sd??", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USB %k"
```

Now against this rule, a `helloworld` script runs located in `/usr/local/bin/USB`. The script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello World!' >>"/home/<username>/Desktop/udev.out"
exit
```

This works perfectly well when I plug in my USB drive into my host Ubuntu machine. But when I do the same in my Debian machine, it doesn't respond. No `udev.out` is created on Desktop. I can detect my USB drive in the guest Debian machine running inside Virtual Box. Why is that?

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's much better! I suspect the problem is down to its being a virtual machine but I'm not sure. How is the drive recognized in Debian? Does it get an `sdX` name?

Comment: @tedron Yes! `sdb`, `sdb1`, `sdc` etc.. I successfully mounted it on my VM, made changes, and it was all fine.

Comment: @tedron, horrendous type above, had `can't` instead of `can`, Now updated.

Comment: No you didn't, I did that. Sorry, I had misunderstood and thought the problem was that the drive was not recognized. Could you [edit] and clarify that the issue is that your udev script is not run when the drive is plugged in?

Comment: @user1343318, use `udevadm monitor --env` then plug  your device, see to see if there any event triggered. Reference: https://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-admin_sd_draft/cha.udev.html